# ng-pattern to validate dd/mm/yy format date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, regex, date, pattern-matching

i have a date picker which accepts date in dd/mm/yy format can someone please say what is the regular expression should be place in ng-pattern to match the same
date will contain only / no other special character
example:12/12/2015

Answer (score 3):

regex for that would be

```
ng-pattern="/\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d/"
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex will be

```
/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[13456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-02-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29-02-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/
```

This is valid for leap years as well. To use this in your application, you can either use it inline with `ng-pattern` or use it as

```
$scope.pattern = new RegExp(PatternAsString);

<input ng-model="foo" ng-pattern="pattern">
```

Comment: just FYI, this regexp accepts dates in the dd-mm-yyyy, not dd/mm/yyyy which is what OP was asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use below pattern. It only validates date format "yyyy/MM/dd".

```
ng-pattern = ^[0-9]{4}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is correct and working fine.

```
ng-pattern="/^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{4}$/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is

```
ng-pattern="/^(31[ \/ ](0[13578]|1[02])[ \/ ](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((29|30)[\/](01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[\/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[\/](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/](18|19|20)[0-9]{2})|(29[\/](02)[\/](((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000))$/"
```

This will take care of Leap year as well.
Format is DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

@ivarni
your condition won't work for 29/oct or 30/oct
your month validation need minor rectification.

What we have: (01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])
Corrected : (01|0[3-9]|1[0-2])

Comment: Ivarni has not asked the question. Why are you addressing him?